# Which number is bigger and by how much for random numbers

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random, void

I'm doing an online tutorial on python, and its asking to write a program that takes two random integers as parameters and display which integar is larger and by how much using a void function. But if both random intgars are the same the def show-larger should handle that too. So in the main section I have written the code to generate 2 random numbers, I'm not sure how to do the next step and call show_larger with the integers as arguments. The example solutions that are given are 3 is larger than 1 by 2 and The integers are equal, both are 3. 
This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
value_1=random.randrange(1,6)
value_2=random.rangrange(1,6)

def show_larger():    
difference= value_1=-value_2
if value_1 == value_2:
    print('The integers are equal, both are' + str(value_1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a simple way of doing it.

```
import random

def main():
    value_1=random.randrange(1,6)
    value_2=random.randrange(1,6)
    show_larger(value_1, value_2)

def show_larger(value_1, value_2):
    if value_1 == value_2:
        print('The integers are equal, both are' + str(value_1))
        return
    else:
        print(("value_1" if value_1>value_2 else "value_2") + "is bigger by" + str(abs(value_1 - value_2)))

main()
```

Comment: with your coding I would still keep the def main (): at the top correct? @intboolstring

Comment: I updated my answer with the `def main()` at the top.

Comment: @CzSzPzTz us my version of `def main()`.

Comment: name 'random' is not defined this is the error message I get when I run it

Comment: Did you import random?  Add `import random` to the top.

Comment: ahh no I didn't let me try it again

Comment: module 'random' has no attribute 'rangrange' -- this is the error now.

Comment: Whoops.  I misspelled `randrange`.  It is fixed in my answer.  It should work this time.

Comment: now it just prints value_1 and not the actual random number

Comment: its saying invalid syntax and highlights main at the end as the problem

Comment: Can you try copying it again?  You may have missed copying one of the `)`s.

Comment: when I run the code it is still print "value_1 or value_2" instead of the actual number that was generated

Comment: Try adding some debugging statements and trace through the code.

Comment: @CzSzPzTz don't edit an answer to reply to it. Post your results in a comment.

Comment: @MattDMo it wont let me take my sentence out